# Service shouldn't stop when the phone is sleeping, or the activity (for starting the service) is not running

Tags: android, service

I want to run a service to collect the accelerometer sensor information and it shouldn't stop when the phone is sleep or the activity (for starting the service) is not running.
I have to send start and stop commands to the service from the menu activity.
currently I am using a bundled service in the same process of the activity but the problem is that it gets closed as soon as activity is closed (return key pressed).

I am wondering if I use a separate process it will resume even if there is no bundled activity (when activity  is closed).

If not, which service model should I choose?

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for startService instead of bindService.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService%28android.content.Intent%29

However, even with startService, there are no guarantees the service will remain running "forever" and "always".

WARNING, the options below will consume a lot of battery.

You can increase the chances the service will not be stopped by changing the priority to startforeground (requires a notification).

While the screen is off, the only way to keep the service "alive all the time" is to use Alarm Manager with an RTC_WAKEUP or ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP schedules.

Less battery...

Practically speaking, however, without startForeground and just using normal RTC or ELAPSED_REALTIME alarm schedules, your service will run most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a service in the same process with your application, even if your activities all closed, the app still work because your service still alive until you call stopservice (the system will restart your service automatically when it is killed by system).  if your service perform complicated communication with activities , i think you should use remote messenger service. During running of service you can bind to service to send and receive data between service and activities.
For more information of service and communicate to service, you can refer [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#RemoteMessengerServiceSample)